# ParseError at /meta/classes/image.bbclass Could not inherit file classes/image_types_uboot.bbclass?

Tags: bitbake, angstrom-linux, imx6

**UPDATE :** It started to bitbake!!
I now get the following error, and it stops to bitbake core-image-minimal in the middle:

```
    Initialising tasks: 100% |##################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:04
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: systemd-1_232-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/systemd/1_232-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch 0001-systemd-udevd.service.in-set-MountFlags-shared.patch
patching file units/systemd-udevd.service.in
Hunk #1 FAILED at 21.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- rejects in file units/systemd-udevd.service.in
Patch 0001-systemd-udevd.service.in-set-MountFlags-shared.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: systemd-1_232-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/systemd/1_232-r0/temp/log.do_patch.1928
ERROR: Task (/home/rama/repositories/poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_232.bb:do_patch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1156 tasks of which 1105 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_232.bb:do_patch
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the build configuration output of bitbake I finally get:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.34.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal-4.8"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "apalis-imx6"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.3.2"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon callconvention-hard cortexa9"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta              
meta-poky         
meta-yocto-bsp    
meta-toradex      = "pyro:a75a2f4272226e924d8c9deb699a19ca9e606a5b"
meta-mender-core  = "pyro:302111e4a79e4844cad536fcc9475764eb254611"
meta-freescale    = "pyro:06178400afbd641a6709473fd21d893dcd3cfbfa"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "pyro:9613dbc02ca970122a01c935bc9e5789ced73a9d"
```

EDIT : as suggested by @Anders I replaced meta-fsl-arm and meta-fsl-arm-extra which were on pyro branch (I checked) with meta-freescale-3rdparty. I now get the following error:

```
ERROR: Layer 'fsl-arm-extra' depends on layer 'freescale-layer', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration
ERROR: Layer 'fsl-arm-extra' depends on layer 'freescale-layer', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration
```

EDIT: It said the file is missing so I supplied it the following file from here http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/classes/image_types_uboot.bbclass?h=daisy

created a file and now I get the following error:

```
ERROR: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-fsl-arm/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-mfgtool-initramfs.bb: No IMAGE_CMD defined for IMAGE_FSTYPES entry 'sdimg' - possibly invalid type name or missing support class
ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-fsl-arm/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-mfgtool-initramfs.bb
```

I tried bitbaking a file, when I did I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ParseError at /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta/classes/image.bbclass:185: Could not inherit file classes/image_types_uboot.bbclass
```

I have the following meta-layers, all on the pyro branch, I tried playing around with the branches I still get the same error somehow :

1. meta
2. meta-mender-core
3. meta-toradex
4. meta-fsl-arm
5. meta-fsl-arm-extra
6. meta-qt5

If I add the meta-angstrom to the above I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-angstrom/recipes-angstrom/angstrom/angstrom-version.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable do_install, expression was     install -d /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc
    echo "Angstrom 2.3.2 (Core edition)" > /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/angstrom-version
    echo "Built from branch: pyro" >> /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/angstrom-version
    echo "Revision: a75a2f4272226e924d8c9deb699a19ca9e606a5b" >> /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/angstrom-version
    echo "Target system: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi" >> /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/angstrom-version

    echo "${@get_layers(bb, d)}" > /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/angstrom-build-info

    echo "VERSION=\"2.3.2\"" > /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/os-release
    echo "VERSION_ID=\"2.3.2\"" > /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/os-release
    echo "NAME=\"Angstrom\"" >> /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/os-release
    echo "ID=\"angstrom\"" >> /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/os-release
    echo "PRETTY_NAME=\"The Ångström Distribution 2.3.2\"" >> /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/os-release
    echo "ANSI_COLOR=\"1;35\"" >> /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/os-release
    echo "HOME_URL=\"http://www.angstrom-distribution.org\"" >> /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/etc/os-release

    install -d /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/usr/bin
    install -m 0755 /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/lsb_release /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/apalis_imx6-poky-linux-gnueabi/angstrom-version/2_2.3.2-r12/image/usr/bin/
 which triggered exception AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getVar'
```

I need to bitbake file and install it on my apalis imx6, do I need this meta-angstrom layer?

If I change the machine to qemux64 and I remove the toradex,fsl,angstrom layers, it starts to bitabke just fine! So its definitely a problem with those layers.

Any help is appreciated!

I am executing this on Ubuntu 14.04

EDIT: <s>Switching to master branch on meta-angstrom I was able to solve the second, error however I still get the first error. Hope this helps somebody else.</s>

EDIT: It seems the problem has recurred, no idea why still investigating

EDIT: When I bit bake I get stuff this like :

```
Loading cache: 100% |############################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 158 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.                    | ETA:  0:00:16
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtdeclarative_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
```

No info on the layers.

My layers are all upto date, and I have switched them to master.
How else can I get layer info?

EDIT: 
This is what I get from bitbake, no other information whatsoever

```
bitbake core-image-minimal
WARNING: Host distribution "ubuntu-14.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.                    | ETA:  0:00:16
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit-examples_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit-examples_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.                    | ETA:  0:00:17
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
```

EDIT : local.conf

```
MACHINE ?= "apalis-imx6"
MENDER_FEATURES_ENABLE_append = " mender-uboot"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
#SDKMACHINE ?= "i686"

EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"

USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"

BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"

PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"

MENDER_ARTIFACT_NAME = "demo-mender-artifact"

INHERIT += "mender-full"
INHERIT += "rm_work"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""

IMAGE_FSTYPES = "ext4"
```

bblayers.conf:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta \
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core \
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-toradex \
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-fsl-arm \
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-fsl-arm-extra \
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-qt5 \
  "
```

I remove meta-angstrom from the layers, it seems to give me some other errors as well.

Am I missing some layers?
I tried adding the meta-openembedded layers like meta-oe and so on, I got some errors like :

```
ERROR: ParseError at /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/maliit/maliit-plugins_git.bb:7: Could not inherit file classes/qt4x11.bbclass
```

so I removed it as well.

Comment: Add info on all layers and their versions, that you're using in your build. Preferably by adding the initial output of running `bitbake`.

Comment: @Anders updated question

Comment: No, you get more info from bitbake, before it starts parsing; there the info about selected machine, distro, build machine, and all added layers are shown. That's the info that will help anyone to help you.

Comment: @Anders I understand what you mean, I have seen it online but this is all I seem to get on my terminal

Comment: @Anders I added a sample of what I get as an output from bitbake

Comment: Can you add your local.conf and bblayers.conf?

Comment: @surendranath done

Comment: What version of bitbake and OpenEmbedded Core are you using? Which versions and branches are being used from the other layers too?

Comment: I cloned the pyro branch, as stated in the question. Thats is the way I setup bitbake https://www.yoctoproject.org/tools-resources/projects/poky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error:

```
ERROR: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-fsl-arm/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-mfgtool-initramfs.bb: No IMAGE_CMD defined for IMAGE_FSTYPES entry 'sdimg' - possibly invalid type name or missing support class
ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-fsl-arm/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-mfgtool-initramfs.bb
```

suggests that one of your layers aren't updated to pyro. Looking further at your issue, `meta-fsl-arm` is severely outdated! (No pyro branch etc). This layer has been replaces by `meta-freescale`.

You probably will have to take a closer look at eg `meta-fsl-arm-extra` too, to see if it's currently maintained and updated or not.

This is the reason I asked you about the exact branches and versions of each layer. There *is* no `pyro` branch for `meta-fsl-arm`!

Comment: I made an update to the question, it started to bitbake I put the output in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really able to follow your question with all the updates in more or less random order... If it's the patch error for systemd your looking at now, you have to find out which layer provides 0001-systemd-udevd.service.in-set-MountFlags-shared.patch, and which other layers patches changes something at the same place or close by as this patch does.

Comment: I was referring to the latest update at the top of the question. So to find which layer provides this patch should I look into the layers files?

Comment: this patch seems to be part of the meta-toradex layer
SRC_URI += " \
    file://rndis.network \
    file://0001-systemd-udevd.service.in-set-MountFlags-shared.patch \
"
in file systemd_%.bbappend file.
not sure what I should be doing after this.

Comment: Well, either remove it, unless you need it. Or perhaps better, try to apply it manually (with all other patches applied), such that you can recreate it.

Comment: You could always try to run `devtool modify systemd`. Though, I've never tried to use it on a recipe which has patches that doesn't apply. In worst case, remove the patch from `meta-toradex`, run the `devtool` command. Then you can manually apply the patch and create a replacement patch for the one in `meta-toradex`. That's about as far as anyone can help you without doing the work. (And I don't have your set of layers in any of my builds).

Comment: Thank you, I will try what you suggested, but if the patch is not present how does one manually apply it?

Comment: Use `patch -p1 >../path_to_patch`